# Stop Chapter Starting New Page in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, layout, itext

Every time I add a Chapter object to my document in iTextSharp it creates a new page. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Is there any code you can provide to show us a simple example?

Comment: Seems as though it isn't possible. This page says:

"The top-level object is a Chapter, which will always begin on a new page...."

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/84/itextsharp-links-and-bookmarks

Comment: Although I learned a lot from Mike's tutorials, they were written almost a decade so they need to be read with that in mind. According to [this page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/chapter-and-section-examples) on the iText developer site _The Chapter and Section objects are being abandoned. They don't have any added value. Creating of bookmarks is done using the PdfOutline object._